# laravel controller : update function for multiple dynamic rows

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

[invoice_service Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkoAL.png) -
[Invoice Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FcJz.png)

the edit function works well in EditInvoice blade and the specific rows are displayed with their value.
Example : if I choose to edit invoice N17 , in EditInvoice blade 2 results will be appear (see table image).

for the next step , I need to update this 2 results value(invoice services).
I try many ways in update function but didnt work.

- store function : works well

```
public function store(Request $request) : 
...
.....
$designation = $request->designation;
$QTE = $request->QTE;
$PU = $request->PU;
$total = $request->total;

$c = count($request->designation);
for ( $i=0; $i< $c; ++$i) { //get all rows(dynamic add/remove)
   $invoice_number = $request->invoice_number;
   $invoice_id = Invoices::latest()->first()->id;
   $services = new invoice_services();
   $services->invoice_number = $invoice_number;
   $services->invoice_id = $invoice_id;
   $services->designation = $designation[$i];
   $services->QTE = $QTE[$i];
   $services->PU = $PU[$i];
   $services->total = $QTE[$i] * $PU[$i];
   $services->save();
}   
..
...
```

- Update function : need editing

```
public function update(Request $request )
    { 
//Here we need to update the rows !! I tried many ways but it didnt work
}
```

- edit function :  works well

```
public function edit($id) { 
$invoices = invoices::where('id', $id)->first();
$services = invoice_services::where('invoice_id' , $id)->get();
$clients = clients::all();
return view('invoices.edit_invoice', compact('clients', 'services' , 'invoices'));
}
```

- edit_invoice view : works well

```
@foreach ($services as $service) 
       <tr>
   <td><input type="text" name="designation[{{ $service->id }}]"  value="{{ $service->designation }}" class="form-control"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="QTE[{{ $service->id }}]" id="QTE'+incrementalRow+'" value="{{ $service->QTE }}" class="form-control"></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="PU[{{ $service->id }}]" id="PU'+incrementalRow+'" value="{{ $service->PU }}" class="form-control"></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="total[{{ $service->id }}]" value="{{ $service->total }}" id="totali'+incrementalRow+'" readonly ></td>
       </tr>
       @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need Model ID's to update them. So you must send the Model IDs in your data array with **POST** (or **PUT** if you have [resource route](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers)). Then in the update function set the attributes and save to for each like below.

```
$models = $request->input("models"); // as an array
foreach($models as $model) {
  $row = Incvoices::findOrFail($model["id"]);
  $row->total = $model["total"];
  $row->save();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this method